# How to Customize the NetSuite Bank Transfer Form and Record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We need to set a default class on the Bank Transfer form in NetSuite. However this form does not have a 'customize' link and there does not appear to be a 'bank transfer', 'transfer funds' or 'transfer' record so a script cannot be deployed and applied to it. Workflows also do not list this record. Is there a way to customize this form or record? It does appear that Bill.com has found a way to create bank transfer records, but it's unclear how they're doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an undocumented Record Type called "transfer", it doesn't show up in record.Type, but if you supply it then it does appear to work.